# Android Number of Background Thread on Device

Tags: android, performance

Is there a way to get the number of background threads running on an Android device?

Comment: do you want http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html?

Comment: @blackbelt I'm trying to get the number of background threads running on the device.  I believe that gives me information about a task running on the device.

Comment: you can enumerate it (get the number of processes) . But I think is not possible to get the number of thread for process

Comment: you can get number of thread in the JVM where you app runs in this way Thread.getAllStackTraces()

Comment: @blackbelt But I need to know if they are background threads.